# values won't get updated in a function because of a ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm writing a javascript function that should change the view of a postcard depending on which case is selected.

My problem is that the old values of the object "m_case" is getting used. If I press the button with class "case-btn" twice I get the right case selected in my postcard view. But I want it to be triggered when I press the button once.

I guess I have to do something like a callback function in the m_case.setCase() function call, but I can't get it working,

```
$('.case-btn').on('click', function() {
    remove_active_state_from_cases();

    m_case.setCase($(this).data('case'));

    // Changes the view of the postcard
    m_postcard.changeBackground(m_case.getPhoto());
    m_postcard.changeMessage(m_case.getMessageText());
    m_postcard.changeFullName(m_case.getFullName());
    m_postcard.changeCountry(m_case.getCountry());

    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

The setCase() function

```
this.setCase = function(id) {
    // Set ID
    this.setID(id);
    var that = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_case_by_id.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {id: that.getID() },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.success) {
                that.setFirstName(data.first_name);
                that.setFullName(data.full_name);
                that.setAdress(data.adress);
                that.setCountry(data.country);
                that.setStamp(data.stamp);
                that.setPhoto(data.photo);
                that.setSummary(data.summary);
                that.setStory(data.story);
                that.setMessageText(data.message_text);
                that.setDefaultMessageText(data.default_message_text);
                that.setMessageImg(data.message_img);
            } else {
                console.log('failure');
            }
        }
```

**EDIT** The problem might be in my AJAX call, I have to wait till the ajax have been called. but how do I continue the first flow when my Ajax is done and not before?

**SOLUTION**

I made it working by adding a callback parameter and calling that function in the ajaxs complete function.

```
$('.case-btn').on('click', function() {
    remove_active_state_from_cases();
    var that = this;

    m_case.setCase($(this).data('case'), function() {

        m_postcard.changeBackground(m_case.getPhoto());
        m_postcard.changeMessage(m_case.getMessageText());
        m_postcard.changeFullName(m_case.getFullName());
        m_postcard.changeCountry(m_case.getCountry());

        $(that).toggleClass('active');
    }); 
});

// Sets the whole case from an id.
this.setCase = function(id, callback) {
    // Set ID
    this.setID(id);
    var that = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_case_by_id.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {id: that.getID() },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.success) {
                that.setFirstName(data.first_name);
                that.setFullName(data.full_name);
                that.setAdress(data.adress);
                that.setCountry(data.country);
                that.setStamp(data.stamp);
                that.setPhoto(data.photo);
                that.setSummary(data.summary);
                that.setStory(data.story);
                that.setMessageText(data.message_text);
                that.setDefaultMessageText(data.default_message_text);
                that.setMessageImg(data.message_img);
            } else {
                console.log('fail big time');
            }
        },
        complete: function() {
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `m_postcard.changeBackground` and other calls should be in the `success` callback, or in another function that is called from the success callback, as those values aren't set till the async ajax call is done.

With the way your code is now the `m_postcard.changeBackground` and other calls are called immediately after your `setCase` function is done executing. This means your methods are executed before the data has arrived from the server

While the ajax is processing you probably should show a loading message on the screen to let the user know they have to wait till the processing is done. Show the message before calling the `.ajax` call and hide it in the success/error callbacks.

Any changes to the site content should be done from the success callback, ie changing `active` states, changing content, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I made it working by adding a callback function as a param and calling that function in the ajaxes complete function, what do you think about that answer?